# Conversion of a jpg or png image to a world file in gazebo

Tags: gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Let's say I have an image of the plan of a building. I want the same map as a 3d world in the gazebo. The plan only consists of walls and I want all the walls in my gazebo model. I know there are API's to build the same thing but working with those API might take a lot of time. So, I`m interested to know if there is an easy workaround for this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21433/conversion-of-a-jpg-or-png-image-to-a-world-file-in-gazebo./) by [kkvamshee](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7502/kkvamshee/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In my case, I had a binary image with black cells representing walls. So, I was able to insert walls(or cuboids) in blender and generate a dae file.

---

Originally posted by [kkvamshee](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7502/kkvamshee/) with karma: 1 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0